# what are root dns server

Tags: domain-name-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the DNS root zone and domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/219881/what-is-the-dns-root-zone-and-domain)

according to what i have understood so far a root dns servers responds to top level domain name resolution requests. Am i correct ?

And why is it that there are only 13 root servers ?

Comment: Have you seen the Wikipedia article?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_nameserver

Comment: If you have any questions left after reading these two links we'd be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 3):

> And why is it that there are only 13 root servers ?

UDP DNS messages are limited to 512 bytes. 13 root server ~ 5oo bytes.

> according to what i have understood so far a root dns servers responds to top level domain name resolution requests. Am i correct ?

Yes.

Comment: how come 13 root servers ~ 500 bytes ?